# How to decode an array from an api

Tags: swift, api

I have the following response from an API :

```
[803442,1605299,1605300,1880804,1880806,1880808,1880810,1880811,1880817,1880819,1880820,1880825,1880826,1880828,1880829,1880830,1880831,1880832,1880833,1880834,1880835,1880836,1880844,1880847,1880849,1880850,1880851,1880862,1880863,1880864]
```

Just an array of Int

I'm trying to decode it using the JSONDecoder but since it does not have a name its confusing me.

If I have something like this

```
{"results":[{"device_id":4085245,"locations":[{"time":1553285663,"lat":2.8019,"lon":-60.7276,"accuracy":80,"seq_number":722},{"time":1553328699,"lat":2.8025,"lon":-60.7266,"accuracy":14503,"seq_number":723}]}]}
```

I know how to do it since I can build the structure like this

```
struct results: Decodable {
    var device_id: Int
    var locations: [locations]
}
struct locations: Decodable {
    var time: Int
    var lat: Double
    var lon: Double
    var accuracy: Double
    var seq_number: Int
}
```

But on the first case I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone have a suggestion please.

Thank you

Comment: Just decode `[Int].self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int` is already `Decodable`, so you can easily decode array of this type

```
do {
    let array = try JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: data)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Reference: [how to declare custom types automatically conforming to `Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types): *The simplest way to make a type codable is to declare its properties using types that are already Codable. These types include standard library types like String, Int, and Double*

Answer (score 0):

Its an `Array` of `Int`.  Since both `Int` and `Array` are already `Codable` you can just directly decode it.  Example Playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let data = "[803442, 1605299, 1605300, 1880804, 1880806, 1880808, 1880810, 1880811, 1880817, 1880819, 1880820, 1880825, 1880826, 1880828, 1880829, 1880830, 1880831, 1880832, 1880833, 1880834, 1880835, 1880836, 1880844, 1880847, 1880849, 1880850, 1880851, 1880862, 1880863, 1880864]".data(using: .utf8)!

if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: data) {
   print(decoded)
}
```